# Java Class Loader Russian Dolls

Tags: java, compilation, jvm, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

Is it possible in Java to create a class loader that loads (or more appropriately reloads) itself?

It could initially be loaded by the default classloader. I imagine a system in Java that is able to modify itself as it is running via compilation and loading cycles. If so, you could create many objects that inherit from your Russian-doll loader to dynamically update their logic.

Comment: How would it load itself if it's not loaded to load itself?

Comment: It would initially be loaded by the default classloader.

Comment: Are you trying to reload the classloader itself ?

Comment: That is the heart of the question. Yes. More specifically, to reload the class from its own logic...not logic in a different class.

Comment: @EricBischoff Please change your question to "Is it possible in Java to create a class loader that **re**loads itself?" `Dynamic Class Loading` and `Dynamic Class Reloading` are different things in java because of how class loading works.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Onur.
Done.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do? It sounds like you are asking how to best implement one approach to achieving an underlying goal, but it might be better to step back and ask if that's the best approach.

Comment: There are two motivations in play:

1.) What underline mechanics are in play with classloading; if a class is already loaded, what is happening with it's memory when it is reloaded. 
AND
2.) There is a goal in mind, to have an object that can be extended to reload any piece of an application dynamically. I know this sort of thing has been done but there are some advantages (and disadvantages) to doing it this new way.

I've already got my class loading working dynamically, but I don't like my options for managing class loaders architecturally. The question just kills two birds. or 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload the *code* of every class whose qualified name doesn’t start with `java.` within another `ClassLoader`, but this doesn’t reload the class. Instead, it creates a new class having the same qualified name but a different defining `ClassLoader`.

See [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification, §5.3. Creation and Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3)

> A class loader `L` may create `C` by defining it directly or by delegating to another class loader. If `L` creates `C` directly, we say that `L` *defines* `C` or, equivalently, that `L` is the *defining loader* of `C`.
>   …
>   At run time, a class or interface is determined not by its name alone, but by a pair: its binary name (§4.2.1) and its defining class loader.

So when you define a class with the same qualified name as an existing using a different class loader instance, you are actually creating a new runtime class. Of course, that class might extend `ClassLoader` and could be used to define again a new class with the same qualified name.

Whether these new classes have identical bytecode, be a modified version or completely unrelated, doesn’t matter.

This is close to how most frameworks supporting reloading of modules work. They create a new class loader (but not a child of the old one), which will “reload” *all* classes of a module, including the unchanged ones, as technically, it creates a zoo of new unrelated classes which must be linked among each other.
The old classes then have to go out of scope, which requires some care. A class loader can only get garbage collected, if *all* of its classes are unused. A single instance of one class could prevent its class loader and all of its defined classes from getting garbage collected…

Comment: Thank you, good answer. So is it true that for a class to successfully reload itself it must both 1.) Get rid of the old version of itself (which is impossible since each class maintains a parent class-loader variable) AND 2.) Update all links? If this is true then the answer is NO, not possible.

Comment: Indeed, the semantic of a full reload can’t be implemented for a `ClassLoader` (only by delegating to another `ClassLoader` actually doing the work). This is not to confuse with true reloading via Instrumentation API, this true reloading has several restrictions and doesn’t change the defining `ClassLoader`.